# Can I avoid `_` in pattern matching with gen_range?

Tags: rust

If I want to `match` the result of a `rand::thread_rng().get_range(1, 3)`, I need to add a `_` value even if **I** know there is only two possible values:

```
match rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 3) {
    1 => println!("1"),
    2 => println!("2"),
    _ => panic!("never happens")
};
```

The `_` case is useless but required.

I understand the compiler can't guess that `gen_range(1, 3)` can only return 1 or 2 but is there a way to avoid adding this useless line `_ => panic!("never happens")` with pattern matching (maybe with some hint to the compiler)? Or do I need to replace the last value (`2`) by `_`?

Comment: Assuming there's not a better solution - you'd probably be better off replacing `panic!` with [`unreachable!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unreachable.html) to better communicate your intent.

Comment: The only "bullet proof" alternative is to use an enum { One, Two }, but it leads to more boilerplate and just forces the range check to be done slightly sooner. This sounds like the use of `_` is one of those "have to make do" circumstances.

Comment: Wow thanks! I did not know this macro!

Comment: @rap-2-h: In this case, you may also be interested in `unimplemented!()`, which is very useful when prototyping! With it, you can leave a branch incomplete or even a whole function implementation, and the compiler won't complain about missing expressions or type mismatches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand the compiler can't guess that `gen_range(1, 3)` can only return 1 or 2

That is correct. `gen_range` returns an `i32` in this case, and an `i32` may have many more values.

> is there a way to avoid adding this useless line `_ => panic!("never happens")`

As was covered in the comments, [`unreachable!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unreachable.html) better expresses your intent than just a plain `panic!`:

```
match rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 3) {
    1 => println!("1"),
    2 => println!("2"),
    _ => unreachable!(),
};
```

> replace the last value (`2`) by `_`?

This would be fine, but the "failure" case when you eventually change the arguments is likely harder to catch:

```
match rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 100) {
    1 => println!("1"),
    _ => println!("2"), // oops!
};
```

A version that panics is more likely to blow up obviously during testing. Which you choose is up to you and your risk tolerance.

> The only "bullet proof" alternative is to use an `enum { One, Two }`, but it leads to more boilerplate and just forces the range check to be done slightly sooner

This works, and would be useful if you wanted to have the equivalent of the `match` multiple times in your code. This consolidates the logic to one location.

I'm a little surprised there isn't a macros 1.1 crate that allows something like `#[derive(Rand)]` for an enum... but there are some crates that seem to make it easier.

In *this specific case*, you could also generate a random boolean and just pick `1` or `2`:

```
if rand::thread_rng().gen() {
    println!("1")
} else {
    println!("2")
}
```